# SQL - Can I have a column referencing one of many tables?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I want to use a single table to store contact information of various entities.

Contacts table example:

[image]

The OwnerId should reference EITHER Users (ID) or Students (ID) as drawn below:

[image]

Is it possible to create multiple foreign key constraints on the OwnerId column? I am using EF Core and would like to do include the contact information of each entity, instead of creating a separate query to get the Contacts, something like:

```
int userId = 1;

var users = _databaseContext.Users.Include(x => x.Contacts).Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
// same with Students
```

instead of:

```
int userId = 1;

var user = _databaseContext.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
var userContacts = _databaseContacts.Contacts.Where(x => x.OwnerId == userId).ToList();
user.Contacts = userContacts;
// same with Students
```

Comment: Isn't a student a user, or vice versa? I.e. I suspect that all users should be in the users table.

Comment: This does seem to be a bit of a design no-no, Have a table of users and a flag to indicate the type of user? with a UserId of 1, a StudentId of 1 and an OwnerId of 1, which row from which table do you want...?

Comment: @jarlh not necessarily. There may also be other entities that are not Students or Users, for example Teachers, for which I also need to store the Contact information. Some Students may be users and some Teachers may be users, but it is not a rule.

Comment: @Stu well, it depends what table I'm reading from / entry point from EF. I should probably also mention that I am using GUIDS, though this does not change what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: And a teacher may be a student etc.

Answer (score 0):

So:

- Everyone is a contact.
- Some contacts are users and some aren't.
- Some contacts are students and some aren't.
- Some contacts are teachers and some aren't.

You could do this sort of thing.

```
CREATE TABLE ContactType (
    ContactType varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ContactType_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContactType)
)

INSERT INTO ContactType (ContactType)
VALUES
    ('Student'),
    ('Teacher')

CREATE TABLE Contact (
    ContactId   uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT(NEWSEQUENTIALID()),
    ContactType varchar(8)       NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT Contact_PK             PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContactId),
    CONSTRAINT User_UQ                UNIQUE (ContactId, ContactType), -- To allow FK that enforces type from Student, Teacher, etc. tables.
    CONSTRAINT Contact_FK_ContactType FOREIGN KEY (ContactType) REFERENCES ContactType (ContactType)
)

CREATE TABLE [User] (
    ContactId uniqueidentifier          NOT NULL,
    Username  varchar(32)  NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT User_PK          PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContactId),
    CONSTRAINT User_UQ_Username UNIQUE (Username),
    CONSTRAINT User_FK_Contact  FOREIGN KEY (ContactId) REFERENCES Contact (ContactId)
)

CREATE TABLE Student (
    ContactId   uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ContactType AS CAST('Student' AS varchar(8)),

    CONSTRAINT Student_PK         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContactId),
    CONSTRAINT Student_FK_Contact FOREIGN KEY (ContactId, ContactType) REFERENCES Contact (ContactId, ContactType)
)

CREATE TABLE Teacher (
    ContactId   uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    ContactType AS CAST('Teacher' AS varchar(8)),

    CONSTRAINT Teacher_PK         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContactId),
    CONSTRAINT Teacher_FK_Contact FOREIGN KEY (ContactId, ContactType) REFERENCES Contact (ContactId, ContactType)
)
```

Comment: Not exactly. Each entity (student, user, teacher) has 0 or more contacts of different types. For example, a Student has 2 contacts - an email address and a cell phone number. Or a user has only one Contact of type email address/cell phone number/home phone number. Any entity has any combination of contacts.

Comment: A database relationship is specific, between two tables. The best way to do what you want would be introducing some table as the parent of User, Student, Teacher, etc., perhaps a table called Person. Then the relationship would be from Person to Contact, and therefore apply to all the subcategories of Person. You might also want to separate email addresses and phone numbers into their own attributes, so you can apply appropriate validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

The answer came to me in a dream: https://entityframework.net/joining

Use EF JOIN to get each entity's contacts based on the OwnerId and the Primary Key of said entity.

Comment: That's a nightmare. No data integrity, no configured relationship with navigation properties. Please look for the *polymorphic associations* (anti) pattern to get an impression of its intricacies and hints for doing it (sort of) right.